# Excel VBA Object Helper Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm where one of my ComboBox's can have different values depending on other variables that the user has selected. Rather than update the contents of a single ComboBox every time the user makes a change, I have created two ComboBox's and simply set the appropriate one as visible. These two ComboBox's have the names "width1_cb" and "width2_cb" respectively.

I have created a helper function to return the currently active ComboBox so that other pieces of my code can use it. Here is the helper function:

```
Function myGetActive(ByVal control As String) As ComboBox
If control = "width" Then
    If width1_cb.Visible = True Then
        Set myGetActive = Me.width1_cb
    ElseIf width2_cb.Visible = True Then
        Set myGetActive = Me.width2_cb
    Else
        Set myGetActive = Nothing
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Unfortunately, this function is not functioning as expected. I have another line of code:

```
Set currentWidth = myGetActive("width")
currentWidth.Value = 5
```

which fails on the second line. I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly here - my best guess is that I am somehow not returning the actual combobox instance in my helper function but instead some sort of copy, but in my research I have not been able to figure out the correct way to accomplish this. Does any one know how I can make this function work as expected?

Update: Debugging efforts I have taken including stepping through the code line-by-line and putting a "watch" within the "myGetActive" function on both the width1_cb and the myGetActive variables. What I find is that the myGetActive variable gets set to type "ComboBox/Combobox" while the width1_cb is "Object/Combobox". What's more, the context for width1_cb is "Input_Window.UserForm_Initialize" while the context for the myGetActive is "Input_Window.myGetActive". The function does exit without any errors though.

Comment: 'ActiveWidth' is not a term that I see defined anywhere in your code above; what is it meant to refer to? I think you'll need to include some more code, including where you actually refer to currentWidth.

Comment: That was intended to be "currentWidth", not "ActiveWidth". I've made the change. Is there any other code that you feel would be helpful? I can add it.

Comment: Does it fail now? Because that could be the only problem. Please go back and debug; if there's something else that produces an error then include that section of the code as well.

Comment: Oh, it was the code here on stackexchange that I messed up. My VBA code was correct all along. I should have just copied and pasted. I've updated the original post with some details about the debugging I have done.

Comment: Generally speaking if you just C&P, make sure you actually understand what you're doing; if you get into the habit of copying and pasting all your coding snippets you won't actually learn the ins and outs of syntax etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been clear. I did _not_ copy my code _from_ VBA _to_ stackexchange as I should have. My original code had the appropriate reference to currentWidth, it did not have the incorrect reference to ActiveWidth, but it still does _not_ function as I expect.

Comment: What is width1_cb / width2_cb? Are those publically defined names? Because if they are the names of comboboxes within your form I believe you will need to use me.width1_cb / me.width2_cb, or something like that. It's kind of like saying Range("A1") without adding sheets(1).Range("A1")

Comment: They are controls on a UserForm (i've added this information to the original post). I am already using the me.width1_cb syntax.

Comment: What is the MatchRequired property of your comboboxes set to? If they are true and 5 is not one of the items in the list then you will receive an error.

Comment: MatchRequired = False for the width1_cb object. In fact, it is False for all objects in question.

Comment: Perhaps both width1_cb and width2_cb are not visible, in which case your function returns nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I just wanted to make a comment about 2 distinct ways for declaring variables:

`Private currentWidth  As ComboBox`

or

`Private currentWidth  As MSForms.ComboBox`

but I can't duplicate the issue you're having. Here is the code I tested with

```
Option Explicit

Private currentWidth  As ComboBox
'Private currentWidth  As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    testCombos
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.width1_cb
        .AddItem "test1"
        .AddItem "test2"
        .AddItem "test3"
    End With
    With Me.width2_cb
        .AddItem "test1"
        .AddItem "test2"
        .AddItem "test3"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub testCombos()
    Set currentWidth = myGetActive("width")
    currentWidth.Value = 5
    Set currentWidth = myGetActive(vbNullString)
    currentWidth.Value = 7
End Sub
```

---

```
Function myGetActive(ByVal control As String) As ComboBox
    If control = "width" Then
        If width1_cb.Visible = True Then
            Set myGetActive = Me.width1_cb
        ElseIf width2_cb.Visible = True Then
            Set myGetActive = Me.width2_cb
        Else
            Set myGetActive = Nothing
        End If
    Else
        If width2_cb.Visible = True Then
            Set myGetActive = Me.width2_cb
        ElseIf width1_cb.Visible = True Then
            Set myGetActive = Me.width1_cb
        Else
            Set myGetActive = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

.

[image]

Comment: Somehow, I am also now unable to duplicate this issue.

Comment: Not ideal that we couldn't find out what caused the initial problem, but I'm glad it's working for you

Comment: I agree. thanks for taking the time. I'm considering just deleting this question since it seems it wouldn't really help anyone...